# Hangman game: Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Tags: python

I want to stop the game when lives are out.

```
worlds=["baboon","radio","lol"]
lives=6
import random
chosen_world = random.choice(worlds)
display=[]
for _ in range(len(chosen_world)):
    display+="_"
print(display)
end_of_game=False
while not end_of_game:
    guess = input("guess a letter:\n").lower()

    for postition in range(len(chosen_world)) :
        letter = display[postition]

        letter=chosen_world[postition]
    if letter == guess:
     print(display)
if guess not in chosen_world:
    lives-=1
    if lives==0:
         end_of_game=True

    print("YOU LOSE")

if "_" not in display:
    end_of_game=True
    print("YOU WIN")
#program will never stop and will keep counting even if lives are out
```

Comment: Your code formatting isn't correct. Kindly improve it. Also, wdym by *what is wrong*? Is there any error you are getting or the intended output is different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your check needs to be in the while loop. Python uses indentation to determine what scope the code is in.

```
while not end_of_game:
    guess = input("guess a letter:\n").lower()

    for postition in range(len(chosen_world)) :
        letter = display[postition]

        letter=chosen_world[postition]
    if letter == guess:
        print(display)
    if guess not in chosen_world:
        lives-=1
        if lives==0:
            end_of_game=True
```

I think there might still be some things that won't work the way I would expect but it looks like you've got a good start there.